# Using qsort() to sort an array of ints and swap strings

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I want to sort an `int *arr` in descending order and at the same time swap the corresponding elements of a `char **words` array if the second element of the `int *arr` is greater than the first one. How can i do this using `qsort()` and the `cmpfunc()` ? Sorting the `ints` was easy but how would i go about swapping strings in another array since i have no index of which two elements of the int array are currently sorted?

```
qsort(arr,N,sizeof(int),cmpfunc);
```

``

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
    int val1 = *(int *)a;
    int val2 = *(int *)b;

    if(val2 > val1) {
        /* swap string positions */
        return 1;
    } else if(val2 < val1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to create another data structure "linking" between the two arrays, and write the comparison function for it.

Comment: ... or if the elements of `arr` happen to be indices of elements of `words`, and you want the appearance of sorting `words` the same way you do `arr`, then maybe you don't swap elements of `words` at all.  In that case, you could instead indirect indexed access to `words` through `arr`.  For example, `words[arr[i]]`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sadly, that's not the case and also how would i do `arr[i]` since i have no `i` in the `cmpfunc`?

Comment: Why do you have them in two different arrays? Why not make an array of structs, where the struct contains both the integer and the string?

Comment: if `arr` were available in `cmpfunc` (e.g. because it is a variable at file scope), then you could derive the indizes; But that's a hack, of course.

Comment: @Barmar so something like: `struct obj { int count; char *word; };` and then create an array of N such structs and pass that array in the qsort as base?

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail Yes. You will also need the corresponding comparison function working with this type.

Comment: @EugeneSh. , so i guess something like `int cmpfunc(const void *structa, const void *structb) {}` and inside i would cast those `void *` to `struct obj *` and access their fields from there using the `->` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this. First, a straightfoward answer to your question:

1. Make a new array of `size_t`, containing the values 0 .. `N`.
2. Run `qsort` on that array, where instead of

```
int val1 = *(int *)a;
int val2 = *(int *)b;
```

you do

```
int val1 = arr[*(int *)a];
int val2 = arr[*(int *)b];
```

and then compare as usual.

3. Now you have an array of *indices* of `arr` (a permutation), in the order that will put `arr` in order. Now we can *apply* that permutation to both `arr` and `words`. One option is simply to loop over the array of indices whenever you want to access the two arrays in sorted order. Another is to copy both arrays, then copy the elements back in according to the permutation.

Second: you can also do the same thing with an array of `struct { int * ; char ** }` (each one pointing to one member of `arr` and the corresponding member of `words`), sort this array by its int member while leaving the original arrays in place, and use it from there on.

Third: You can *quit having parallel arrays* to begin with. If the data is so closely associated, then why is it in two unrelated variables? If you put the two kinds of data in a structure together to begin with, then you can sort the array of structures, and do anything else you want with those structures, without worrying that the correlation will get out of sync.

Comment: you are right, i think i should refactor my code and implement the third way you just mentioned. One question i still have is that would the compare function for those structs be something like this: `int cmpfun(const void *a,const void *b) { struct obj a = *(struct obj b *) a; // same for b and then can i access their fields by using the . operator on each of the structs? }`

Comment: i just implemented the third way you just mentioned but the string swapping is not working as expected. Would you mind taking a look at that part of the code with me please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `qsort_r()` (if available, it is a GNU extension. With Microsoft environments it is called `qsort_s()`, but has otherwise the same semantics) to pass another argument to the compare function, for example the base array pointers `int *arr` and `char **words` in a struct:

```
struct cmpargs {
    int *arr;
    char **words;
} args;

...

args.arr = arr;
args.words = words;

qsort_r(arr,N,sizeof(int),cmpfunc, &args);
```

And in your compare function you have now access to these and can use them to swap:

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b, void *_args) {
    struct cmpargs args = _args;

    int *a1 = a;
    int *a2 = b;

    int idx1 = a - args->arr;
    int idx2 = b - args->arr;
```

Now you can swap the elements in the corresponding array `args->word` in your compare function if it would return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to sort an `int *arr` in descending order and at the same time
>   swap the corresponding elements of a `char **words` array if the second
>   element of the int `*arr` is greater than the first one. How can i do
>   this using `qsort()` and the `cmpfunc()` ?

There is no clean way to do this job as presented, because it requires contextual information that `qsort()` does not convey to the comparison function: the base addresses of the `arr` and `words` arrays.  In fact, the latter is not even conveyed to `qsort()` itself in the first place.

In an implementation that supports C11 threads, a viable alternative is to store those pointers in [thread-specific storage](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26.6), and let the comparison function retrieve them from there.  You can then compute the indices of the elements being compared as the pointer differences between them and the base pointer, and you can perform a normal swap of the `words` using its base pointer and the indices you obtained.

**But this probably is not what you really want!**  I infer that you're trying to get the same permutation of the elements of `words` that you do of the elements of `arr`. What you describe is in no way certain to produce that, because you cannot at all be sure that `qsort()` will perform a swap every time the comparison result goes a certain way.

If indeed the two arrays must be separate, the right way to do this is to prepare and sort an auxiliary array of some kind.  There are several alternatives in that area that will then allow you either to reorder one or both of the main arrays, or to access them as if you had done.  For example, you might prepare an `int (*perm)[2]`, with each element (an `int[2]`) containing the corresponding element of `arr` and that element's initial index.  You then sort that array of arrays as you like, and get out the permutation rather directly.  You can then either reorder `arr` and `words` to match, or indirect accesses to them through the permutation (`words[perm[k][1]]`).

But you could also **consider writing your own for-purpose sort function** instead of using `qsort()`.  Such a function could take as arguments the base pointers to both arrays -- correctly typed, even -- and then perform the co-sorting you require, directly.